# How to stop spam email on lumia 635 on my outlook account

Tags: email

I'm being overwhelmed with spam email on my lumia 635 phone from my outlook account. It is blocked on my desktop computer. Is there a way to block it on the phone?

Comment: Is this an outlook.com account, or your corporate Outlook (Exchange) account?

Comment: On your PC, is it filtering out to a junk message folder?

Comment: Just add the sender to blocked list at Outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

You should try doing the filtering on the Outlook.com website.  Flag a bunch of "junk" emails as junk there or set up a filter to put them in your junk email folder.